# Why do people edit, but not leave comments?

Tags: discussion, editing, comments

I have seen some people edit posts but not leave a comment where necessary. For example; a newcomer on this site might have asked a question which contains a lot of grammatical error. But this question could have been improved if the person had provided images (in other cases files, videos, etc.). Now the grammatical part can be solved by editing the question. But the other part is something that can be asked for in the comments. Like, "Please provide images of your problem"

Now the thing is that people do edit these posts but don't leave these comments. At first I thought that this was just score-hunting. But some of the people who do these edits don't earn any repuation out of it as they are well above 2000 points. I know that everyone's time is valueable. But if they have the time to edit the question, then a small comment should not be too much of a trouble right?

Comment: I can only speak for myself, but I've encountered a few "newcomers" here who were kindly asked to supplement their question with more details and/or images, but ignored the request. That's why I sometimes edit questions/answers without comment, if this can increase the quality of the post.

Comment: Editing questions takes considerable time and effort, leaving an additional comment  on top of that adds up. Comments are often not fully addressed or outright ignored by users. If the editor already did the work himself, the reasons should be self explanatory in the edit itself, there less incentive to leave an additional comment

Comment: This. And personally, I honestly stopped caring because I know well that virtually nobody reads them. Most of them would be any of the following "fixed tags/punctuation/grammar/images/formatting" and a short glance at the side-by-side comparison is often self-explanatory. And when it's not, I already spent a lot of time editing anyway, I want to move on before becoming a grinch x)

Comment: well it's not like we are editing code, that may involve complex edits to several files where it's definitely crucial to leave comments for every commit within a version-controlled code base :)

Comment: Most of the time when I edit something, it is about grammar or fixing terminology to make questions/answers easier to find for people who search for the correct (Blender-used) terms, so I think this does not require a comment... And as quellenform already said, comments asking for clarification or details, images etc. are often ignored so I've often given up on that. And apart from that, very often commenters immediately demand files when I think, I already understood what the problem is, so I write no comment for it although others might ask for details.